# DJANGO, NGINX and WINDOWS SERVER

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have deployed a django application using nginx.
These are the nginx configurations I configured.

**c:/nginx/sites-available/project_nginx.conf & c:/nginx/sites-enabled/project_nginx.conf
**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    192.168.xxx.xx;

    location /static {
        alias D:/project/apps/media;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias D:/project/apps/media;
    }
        
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

**c:/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
**

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include.       mime.types;
    default_type   application/octet-stream;
    include        C:/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/project_nginx.conf
    ...
```

I have successfully deployed it and it is running without any problem on the server but,

**NB: The server is a windows server**

**the problem is that, I cannot access the software on other PCs which are on the same network.
What is a possible solution to this problem?**

I need the application to be accessible with other PCs on the intranet.